# How to run multiple jobs on a GPU grid with CUDA using SLURM

Tags: simulation, hpc, slurm

I've been working on speeding up processing time on a job using CUDA. Usually this would be fairly straightforward, however I've run into a rather interesting problem. We are using slurm to schedule our jobs, and through adding CUDA code and enabling the compilation of it, it has decreased individual job time by half. The issue arises when looking at the loading on the GPUs. Before enabling CUDA we have the possibility of running 6 jobs per node. However, after enabling CUDA we can only run 2 jobs per node - 1 on each GPU.

Initially, thinking there was something wrong with my submission script, I went and tried adding:

```
--ntasks-per-node=6
```

to the submission command.

This returns an error stating:

```
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Requested node configuration is not available
```

This leads me to believe that my slurm.conf is not configured properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can't exactly post the slurm.conf, but I can look at any settings and/or change them on suggestion.

Edit: accidentally hit enter when filling out tags before ready to submit question.

Comment: You probably have 2 GPUs per node, so you can only start 2 GPU jobs in each node. you should be able to start non-GPU jobs in nodes that are already running 2 GPU jobs simultaneously. Also, just because you cannot have more than one task accessing the GPU simultaneously, asking for more than 2 tasks per node (if they are GPU tasks) is not supportes by your cluster, because you don't have hardware for that request.

Comment: We do. We are using K80s on each node. The job we are trying to run is mostly a CPU centric job. Only one aspect of the job is using openGL and CUDA. Before introducing CUDA to the job, we would run up to 6 jobs on each node, all using openGL. Does CUDA just not play friendly when sharing GPUs?

Comment: CUDA is as friendy sharing GPUs as C/Java/Python/whatever is as friendly sharing CPUs. If you ask for a GPU, the GPU is for that process. If you only have N GPUs, then you can only have N jobs asking for a GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that we had a hidden gres=gpu:1 inside of our slurm.conf. Removing this allowed us (in our case limited for CPU load reasons) to submit up to six CUDA + OpenGL jobs to a node with one K80 GPU.